# Getting Branch's Deeplink key value through Facebook ads

Tags: facebook, branch, git-branch, facebook-ads-api, branch.io

I have created a Branch link with some keys and values.
My app uses those values for multiple reasons. It works well when I open the link directly on my mobile browser or from a message.

But I want to use this link in a Facebook App download ad campaign. I have putted it as the ad deeplink. But when I install and then open the app via the ad thoses values are not sent.

Does anyone has managed to send keys/values via a branch link through a Facebook ad ?

Thanks
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Jackie from Branch here.
Branch supports deep-linked Facebook ads. We've created an FAQ page exactly for this and there are a few things you can check to diagnose the issue. You can go through them here (https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linked-ads/facebook-ads-faq/#troubleshooting-deep-linking). I'd also encourage you to use Facebook's tester tool, as mentioned in our FAQ doc.

Hope this helps. If you continue to experience issues, please feel free to reach out to us directly at integrations@branch.io. When you do, be sure to include your Branch app ID and the ad links you're using so that we can investigate further!